# In AG Grid, is there a way to differentiate when a user re-sizes a singl column vs when all columns are re-sized?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am building a feature that needs to persist the state of an AG Grid when a user modifies it (either re-orders or re-sizes columns).

However, the implementation requires us to call `api.resizeColumnsToFit()` in order to make sure the initial load doesn't produce unwanted horizontal scrollbars. The trouble is that calling this method triggers the `columnResized` event for all columns. I only want to trigger that event when the user deliberately resizes a column.

Unfortuantely, I don't see a way to differentiate between a user resizing a column and the api being called to make sure all columns fit in the viewport. As such, I'll be needlessly saving grid state when the page loads.

Is there a specific event to watch for?